# App crashes when launching directly from simulator but If I launch our app in the simulator from Xcode via the play button it runs just fine

Tags: xcode, crash, ios-simulator

In latest Xcode 12.5 and iOS simulators If I launch our app in the simulator from Xcode via the play button it runs just fine

If I launch our app in the simulator by tapping on the app icon the splash screen comes up and then it seems like the app crashes

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR - Check out the Crash Log automatically created in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports when an app crashes.

Since no one has answered this in five months, yet this is the first item appearing in my google search results, I’ll add an answer (the standard response would be: “this has been asked before” or “you haven’t provided enough information to help diagnose the problem”)

I had the same problem, and this is how I figured out what the problem is. Your problem/solution is probably different, but using this technique should give you a better understanding of where the problem lies.

> If your iOS app crashes in the Simulator during a test run, the crash report can be used for diagnosing the exact cause of the crash.

When you run (or attempt to run) an app in the simulator and it crashes, a crash log is created on your mac. Currently (Xcode 13.x/14.x), this log can found at:

```
~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
```

tap on the launch icon, and then
open a finder window at:  ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports

sort by date and open the most recent crash log file

(it will start with the name of the app and have an extension of “.crash”)

in my case the crash report stated:

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @rpath/MainAppCore.framework/MainAppCore

I tapped on the main target and examined the list of all included libraries — “Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content”

Sure enough, I found that this particular module was missing from the list. I tapped on the  “+” button and added it to the list.
After recompiling everything worked as expected.