# metro bundler doesnt connect to ios simulator, but builder shows simulator

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, metro-bundler

I'm trying to run iOS simulator for my react native app `react-native run-ios`. it builds and metro bundler CLI runs, the device simulator is running, but the app does not connect with the metro bundler.

im running "react-native": "0.66.0"
xcode 13.0

I kill all simulators 1st. then run the cmd `react-native run-ios`

1st window builds the app and launches window 2

```
$ react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "app.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 13 Pro Max (iOS 15.0)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace app.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme app-local -destination id=28EE92ED-7ADA-4A93-998F-1DB295E06A73")
success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-clbjkkdzbwdgfsfruhrufuliemky/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/app-dev.app"
info Launching "com.myapp.app.dev"
success Successfully launched the app on the simulator
✨  Done in 168.65s.
 %
```

window2 the metro bundler, cant find the simulator.

```
[metro welcome ascii art]
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app...
```

window3, the ios simulator

- iphone 13 pro max is open and running. but my app is not running
- I see my app icon. and i try to run it, but its auto closes, with window 2 message showing "warn No apps connected..." message.

What I tried and doesnt do anything

- removed node_modules and ran `yarn install`
- removed podfile.lock and pod folder. ran `pod install`
- made sure xcode > product > scheme > build config > debug. not release.
- `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- uninstalled xcode, npm, yarn, src code and rebooted. then installed everything back again.

any help?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? run your app on the simulator? or something else? if you are trying to run the app on the simulator then it is working I think as per your 1st window steps

Comment: yes i want to run in ios simulator. it is not working, bc the app does not open. see "warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
info Reloading app..."

Answer (score -1):

this solved it. check the crash log.
`~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`
[App crashes when launching directly from simulator but If I launch our app in the simulator from Xcode via the play button it runs just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69195845/app-crashes-when-launching-directly-from-simulator-but-if-i-launch-our-app-in-th)